# Angular frontend, for Flask api, all inside docker

Tags: python, angular, docker, nginx, flask

I have a problem witch Angular and Flask inside Docker.

Angular linking to Flask app inside docker, but when I want to make http requests to API from Angular returns error.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xPkn.png)

My Angular service for make requests.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,Response } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {User} from './user';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};


@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LoginService {
  private loginUrl = "http://waiter_flask_1:5000/api/account/login";


  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient
  ) { }


  loginUSer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl,{"username":"test","password":"test"},httpOptions).pipe(
      map((response:Response)=>response)

    );
  }



}
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  flask:
    image: flask
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./run.py:/app/run.py
      - ./api:/app/api
    links:
      - database:waiter_database_1


  angular:
    image: angular
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-angular:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - flask:waiter_flask_1
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the request from the Angular app, your browser is making the request, not the `angular` container. Therefore your host machine that you are running your browser from will try to resolve the `http://waiter_flask_1:5000` host not the `angular` container, and since your host cannot resolve the name `waiter_flask_1`, the request will fail.

What you need to do is replace the url your angular app is using to make the HTTP request with a url that your host is able to resolve e.g:

```
http://host.ip.address:5000/api/account/login
```

where `host.ip.address` is the ip address for the host running the `flask` container. If, for example, you are running the `flask` container on the same host that you are accessing your browser, then your url can point to `localhost`, eg:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/account/login
```

Comment: @FaalSta that's great, happy you got it working :). If this answer was what helped you to get it working, please mark it as the accepted answer so other people will know if it does solve the issue in your question.